# to_sym error when using sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, routes

I have a "cart" model, a users cart id is stored in their session.

My routes look like this

```
map.resources :carts
map.cart "cart", :controller => "carts", :action => "show"
```

in my show view, i displayed the contents of the cart, and everything was fine.
Then i decided i wanted the user to be able to update the quantity of items from the show view, so i added this to the view..

```
<% form_for @cart do |cart_form| %>
<% end %>
```

and now i get the following error

```
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

on

```
<% form_for @cart do |cart_form| %>
```

Interestingly if i remove

```
map.cart "cart", :controller => "carts", :action => "show"
```

from my routes, and specify a cart id in the url, it works, but i do not want to be passing cart ids in the url.

Any idea how to fix this please?

[update]

rake routes looks like this:

```
carts GET    /carts(.:format)                               {:controller=>"carts", :action=>"index"}
POST   /carts(.:format)                               {:controller=>"carts", :action=>"create"}
new_cart GET    /carts/new(.:format)                           {:controller=>"carts", :action=>"new"}
edit_cart GET    /carts/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:controller=>"carts", :action=>"edit"}
GET    /carts/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"carts", :action=>"show"}
PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"carts", :action=>"update"}
DELETE /carts/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"carts", :action=>"destroy"}
cart        /cart           {:controller=>"carts", :action=>"show"}
```

Comment: How are you setting the value of @cart? It sounds like that is what is nil so might be worth including that part of your code.

Comment: @cart is valid, it gets set from the session in a application_controller method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the id in the routes, you could use:

```
map.resource :cart, :controller => :carts
```

Comment: replacing my two routes with what you suggested worked great, thanks, but i don't really understand why. Were my routes conflicting?

Comment: what was the output of 'rake gems' with the old routes?

Comment: I can't see why it should crash with the routes you had defined, can you show me a trace of the error you got?